# Vala: Understanding Struct Properties in Classes

Tags: vala

I am currently in the process of working my way through the Vala tutorial at https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial. Now I have stumbled across one section that I need some further explanation for; in the part on object properties at the very end the tutorial introduces struct properties. An example is given that illustrates how one retrieves such a property:

```
struct Color
{
    public uint32 argb;

    public Color() { argb = 0x12345678; }
}

class Shape: GLib.Object
{
    public Color c { get; set; default = Color(); }
}

int main()
{
    Color? c = null;
    Shape s = new Shape();
    s.get("c", out c);
}
```

The tutorial states: "This way, `c` is an reference instead of an instance of Color on stack. What you passed into `s.get()` is `Color **` instead of `Color *.`"

My question is about the statement above. First, could somebody please elaborate on what is meant by "What you passed into `s.get()` is `Color **` instead of `Color *.`". Also, does this imply that the following

```
int main()
{
    Shape s = new Shape();
    Color c = s.c;
}
```

results in the *value* of `s.c` being assigned to `c`?

Edit: I ran the above example in `valac -C structs.vala`. The relevant C equivalent of the `main` method is

```
gint _vala_main (void) {
    gint result = 0;
    Color* c = NULL;
    Shape* s = NULL;
    Shape* _tmp0_ = NULL;
    c = NULL;
    _tmp0_ = shape_new ();
    s = _tmp0_;
    g_object_get ((GObject*) s, "c", &c, NULL);
    result = 0;
    _g_object_unref0 (s);
    _color_free0 (c);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`valac` compiles Vala code into C code which is then compiled by the C compiler (usually GCC) to the target format (e.g. an object file, a library or an executable).

So what the tutorial is talking about when saying `Color**` is that the generated C code will be passing a `pointer to a pointer to a Color struct` to the function (which is [`gobject_get`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-get) in the generated C code).

Structs are value types in C and in Vala* which means that all their memory is copied on assignment. A `Color?` in Vala (a `nullable Color`) is equivalent to a `Color*` (a `pointer to Color`) in C.

Vala translates `ref` and `out` parameters to pointers in C as well, so you get a double pointer (`pointer to a pointer`) when calling an `out` or `ref` parameter with a nullable struct variable.

C is less strongly typed than Vala, that's the reason that a lot of Vala constructs end up being pointers in C. C uses pointer to state optional things, references, call-by-reference parameters, arrays / strings, linked lists and some other more obscure things (like function pointers and Generics).

As to your second question: A copy will be made* when directly assigning to a struct variable.

*[See this question with a great answer by AlThomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194399/struct-is-not-passed-by-reference-when-passed-to-a-method) which explains when copying is going on in the Vala and C levels.

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaborate answer and for the reference you provided. For what it's worth I have added the compiled C output to my question; Apparently the Color pointer `c` is passed as a reference: `g_object_get ((GObject*) s, "c", &c, NULL);`

Comment: Ok, it seems the compiler is being more clever than I first thought in this case. Using `-C` is a good idea when looking for things like this anyway :).